# testNG priorities & dependencies Conflict

Tags: java, testng

I have 2 classes.
1) UpdateCustomerAddress 
2) ResetCustomerPassword

```
UpdateCustomerAddress class is having 5 test methods

@Test(priority = 0)
public void createAddresses() { .... }

@Test(priority = 1, dependsOnMethods ={"createAddresses"})
public void updateAddress()  { ... }

@Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods ={"createAddresses"})
public void setDefaultBillingAndShippingAddress()  { ... }

@Test(priority = 3, dependsOnMethods ={"createAddresses"})
public void deleteAddress()  { ... }

@Test(priority = 4, dependsOnMethods ={"createAddresses"})
public void getAddress()  { ... }



 ResetCustomerPassword is having 2 test methods
    @Test()
    public void validPasswordReset(){ ... }

    @Test()
    public void invalidPasswordResetMissingAttribute(){ ... }



 **testng.xml**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
        <test name="Mandatory test suite" preserve-order="true">
            <classes>
                <class name="webservice.customer.UpdateCustomerAddress" />
                <class name="webservice.customer.ResetCustomerPassword" />

            </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->

        <test name="Api test">

            <packages>
                <package name="webservice.cms"></package>
                <package name="webservice.catalog"></package>
            </packages>
        </test>

    </suite>
```

If I don't set priority to tests inside ResetCustomerPassword class. TestNG will only execute the createAddresses test in UpdateCustomerAddress class and then skipped remaining 4 tests and then move on to ResetCustomerPassword to execute the 2 tests.

if I set priority higher than UpdateCustomerAddress class then it will work fine. TestNg will execute 5 tests in UpdateCustomerAddress class and then executed 2 tests in ResetCustomerPassword.

```
ResetCustomerPassword is having 2 test methods
    @Test(priority = 5)
    public void validPasswordReset(){ ... }

    @Test(priority = 6)
    public void invalidPasswordResetMissingAttribute(){ ... }
```

This is not ideal as in future it may conflict with other test methods.

I've tried grouping 4 tests are dependent on createAddresses() method in UpdateCustomerAddress class, but it did not work.

What will be the ideal situation to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks , all the test method is executed for me with priority and without priority . I am just giving some additional info.

```
priority -> priority will be applied within a class and execution will be happened based on the ascending order rank.

dependsOnMethods --> It specifies the list of methods this method depends on. Dependent Method will be executed first and then corresponding test method will be executed. If the dependent method fails, then actual test method will be skipped.
```

If you want to execute the test in some specific order, then use the priority within the class(priority can be started from 0 in ResetCustomerPassword  as well and it is not necessary to use priority continuation of previous class) else, Test method will be executed in some random order.